# 302 and 301 redirecting problem , while share the link in facebook in laravel

Tags: laravel, redirect, header

[facebook debugger error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3KIK.jpg)

I have a problem with laravel project. I have added the og tags in my page, but while submitting my URL the facebook or some other social media, the URL is redirecting to some other location. I don't know why its happening, please help me. its argent, note: sorry I am not good at English.

Answer (score 1):

When accessing the url http://wannahelp.com/whapi/swap/sw1820104201114-pulser-150-for-sale-bangalure-sw1820104201114 I get a 302 to http://wannahelp.com/whapi and then a 301 to http://wannahelp.com/whapi/. The last one also happens if I browse http://wannahelp.com/whapi, I get a 301 to http://wannahelp.com/whapi/

Check why the first url is returning a 302. Maybe the advert is not public/enabled?

Hope this helps